# Tag synonym request - [tfpt] -> [tfs-power-tools]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The tags [tfpt](/questions/tagged/tfpt) and [tfs-power-tools](/questions/tagged/tfs-power-tools) appear to refer to the same thing.

I'm mostly suggesting the synonym as a [recent tag wiki edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2156504) seems to confuse this with TFTP.

The more verbose tag is likely clearer and won't be as confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synonymized and merged the small amount of questions.

[tfs-power-tools](/questions/tagged/tfs-power-tools) ← [tfpt](/questions/tagged/tfpt)